# Event registration emails sent from wrong email address

Tags: civievent, email, registration, confirmation

We're using civicrm 7.x-5.40.1 on Drupal 7.82

We run a number of events and send out automated confirmation emails when someone registers. We set up each event to use Events as the "From Name" and "events@ourdomain.co.uk" as the "From Email".

That's also set up as a "From Email" in the CRM as a whole.

This has been working as expected for a couple of years but has now stopped and everything is going from "info@..." no matter what we put into the event configuration.

I've tried changing the default email for the site and also for the SMTP(SparkPost) but that doesn't make any difference.

As far as we know nothing has changed, we haven't upgrade the release or installed anything new.

Any ideas welcomed!!

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: Just checking that you are actually sending out via SparkPost?  Sending via Gmail can mess with your sender.

Comment: Hi Aidan, and yes all of the email goes out through Sparkpost. Thanks, Rob